# Is there an efficient way to multiply each row (or column) of a dask.array by a vector element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dask

I have a (huge) 2D array in dask, which won't fit in memory, and need to multiply each column by a corresponding number of a vector. I.e, I want to map M(i,j) → x(i)*M(i,j).

I don't think there is any way to modify the elements directly in dask. This is blindingly easy to do in numpy, but it looks like dask multiply doesn't allow for it in the same way.

My current plan has been to make a dask array from the vector, and map a zero matrix (of the same size as the original matrix) to repeat the vector chunk and pass them back.

```
M = da.from_array( the_matix  , chunks = chunks )
x = da.from_array( the_vector , chunks = chunks ) 

def fn(x, block_id=None): 
   ret = x.blocks[ block_id[0] ].compute()
   ret = np.repeat( ret[:,np.newaxis] , M.shape[1] , axis = 1 )
   return ret

temp = da.zeros( chunks=M.chunks , shape=M.shape )
temp = temp.map_blocks( fn , dtype=float )
M = da.multiply( [ M , temp ] )
```

This seems to be wildly inefficient though and involves a horrifying amount of RAM usage for such a simple task. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Doing like in the example below does not work ?

```
from dask.array import from_array, multiply
from numpy import array
M = from_array(array([[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13,14]]))
vector = from_array(array([1,2,3]))
multiply(M.T, vector).T.compute()
```

Output :

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 12, 14, 16, 18],
       [30, 33, 36, 39, 42]])
```

I've checked it also works with :

```
import dask.array as da
M = da.random.random((10000, 10000), chunks=(1000, 1000))
vector = da.random.random((10000, 1), chunks=(1000, 1000))
result = multiply(M.T, vector).T
```